# Need help with finding the value using trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

Given: $\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha= \alpha$.

Determine the value of $\sin\alpha\times\cos \alpha$

[Link to the image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlzoL.png)

Comment: I think the question reads "$\sin \alpha+\cos\alpha=a$".

Comment: Done! What else do you want me to do?

Answer (score 2):

Given $\sin(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)=a$, we find the value of $\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$. $$\sin(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)=a\implies(\sin(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha))^2=a^2\implies\sin^2(\alpha)+2\cos(\alpha)\sin(\alpha)+\cos^2(\alpha)=a^2$$

by using $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$. Then recall $\cos^2(\alpha)+
\sin^2(\alpha)=1$. Can you go from here?

Comment: Can you continue because im a bit confused on how to find the value for Sin alpha times Cos alpha

Comment: Im confused on how to find it

Comment: And why did you square it?

Comment: I squared because squaring both sides of any equation of the form $x+y=c$ pops out a $xy$ on the left. And since $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$, things work out nicely due to $(x+y)^2=(x^2+y^2)+2xy$.

Comment: Why is there a 2cos(x)sin(x) after being squared?

Comment: Oh ok then afterwards what needs to be done?

Comment: Is it possible to show the way because Im new to this concept

Comment: I mean after squaring

Comment: Rearrange... $\sin^2(\alpha)+2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)+\cos^2(\alpha)=a^2\implies (\sin^2(\alpha)+\cos^2(\alpha))+2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)=a^2$, then follow my answer.

Comment: Oh ok so is that the answer and how to get it? or its still not done?

Comment: So after that what do I do?

Comment: Oh ok sorry for the inconvenience because im still new to this site

Answer (score 2):

Square the equation and use the fact that. $$\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$$